# How to retrieve Firebase data and bind it to a list view?

Tags: android, json, listview, firebase

I am new to Firebase, and am trying to implement it into my Android app. At this moment, I have a list view where I want to show `scheduleTime` and `scheduleName`. Let's call this list view `lvTodaySchedule`. 
Next, this is how my data in Firebase looks like

```
    {
  "schedule" : {
    "-JvA3muNBCoTISLalZZq" : {
      "date" : "24 July 2015",
      "schedule description" : "Bring some sandwiches and apples",
      "schedule name" : "Picnic",
      "selected route" : "Route 1",
      "time" : "0:52"
    },
    "-JvA3muNdSdSasdlZAsS" : {
      "date" : "24 July 2015",
      "description" : "Run around like mad for 20 minutes",
      "schedule name" : "CARDIO",
      "selected route" : "Route 1",
      "time" : "0:41"
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to do is retrieve the date, time and name. So basically in SQL logic, retrieve time and name WHERE date = 24 JULY 2015, and the display it ORDER BY time.
The firebase tutorial teaches me to retrieve a dataSnapshot (which is an Object) of the above data, but I have no idea what to do with it.
I also want to display all these info into the list view, so I was wondering if it's possible to retrieve the data and put them in an array or something.

Comment: *Firebase engineer here* Not an answer, but two good places to find out how to bind the data from Firebase to your Android UI are the sampel AndroidChat app (https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat) and Firebase's new codelab for Android (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JJ_5E9aGgxKJjC2vqT0U0vvNvIzqmlRttiUP2elT90o/). Let me know if you're having trouble with either of them.